# confidence interval and pivotal functions

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, pivot

I am struggling with this question;

> *Given the density function: $$f(x;θ) =  \begin{cases}\dfrac{2(θ−x)}{θ^2} &\text{ if }0< x<θ\\ 0
> > &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$*
>   *the upper limit of a $(1 − α) × 100%$ lower confidence interval for θ can be defined via the bound $L_1$ such that $$P(Y < L_1) = 1 − α$$
>   where Y is a pivotal function for θ.*
>
> 1. *Find the value of $L_1$ such that it constitutes the upper limit of a 90% lower confidence interval on θ.*
> 2. *Explicitly write the 90% lower confidence interval when X = 1.36.*

I understand that a pivotal function is not dependent on θ, but is a function of it. I have determined that $Y=\dfrac{X}{θ}$ is a pivotal function of $f(x;θ)$.

I guess I need to substitute α for .9 and find some point on a function (the pivotal function?) where the area under the curve is 90%. However I don't really know how to do that, do I need to fund the pdf of my pivotal function?

I am generally just stuck for direction on how to solve this.

Comment: It seems to me that your first task is to identify a suitable pivotal quantity.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Please add the `self-study` tag, read its [tag-wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and modify your question to follow the guidelines on asking such questions. In particular, you'll need to clearly identify what you've done to solve the problem yourself, and indicate the specific help you need at the point you struck difficulty.

Comment: I guess people don't have to specifically solve it for me, I am looking for steps on what I need to do. eg. step 1) find the pdf of the pivotal functions, step 2) find the critical value which P(Y <L1) = 0.9 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pivotal function is a transform $\Psi(X,\theta)$ of the pair data x parameter, $(X,\theta)$, such that its distribution is independent of $\theta$. If $\Psi(\cdot,\cdot)$ is real-valued, this means for instance that the quantiles of the distribution of $\Psi(X,\theta)$ are independent of $\theta$. Hence that there is a fixed $q_\alpha$ such that$$\mathbb{P}(\Psi(X,\theta)\le q_\alpha)=\alpha$$

You state that you found that $Y=X/\theta$ is a pivotal, which is correct since the density of $Y$ is given by the change of variable formula
$$f_Y(y)=f_X(\theta y)\,\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}y}=f_X(\theta y)\,\theta=\dfrac{2(θ−\theta y)}{θ^2}\mathbb{I}_{0<\theta y<\theta}\times \theta=2(1-y)\mathbb{I}_{0<y<1}$$
From this point, you need to find [by regular integration] a $90\%$ quantile for $Y$, i.e. $q_9$ such that $\mathbb{P}(Y\le q_9)=0.9$ and then transform back $Y$ into $X/\theta$ to get a lower bound on $\theta$ and hence a one-sided confidence interval for a given value of $X$.